# Java Data Mining Package (JDMP) Tutorials

Tags: java

I am working on a project to get data from a web crawler and do some text analysis (actual techniques is still up for discussion). I am currently using crawler4j for my web crawling and would like to use Java Data Mining Package (JDMP) for the analysis parts. I considered other package such as Apache Mahout (this is not of the table but I am finding that setting up hadoop/maven setup especially in Windows is difficult). In any case, I would like some tutorial/code that details how to use JDMP. I searched online but couldn't find anything helpful in that regard. If any one can suggest some good JDMP tutorials I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.